# Added more than 20 tableviewcells but after that not able to scroll tableview to see all cells in jonkykong/SideMenu iOS demo application

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Implementing side menu in iOS application using jonkykong/SideMenu library. When i am trying to add more than 20 cells in tableview, after that we cant scroll tableview up.

Check source code:
https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Expected result:
We can scroll tableview up if more cells are there.
[image]

Comment: Can you show some example of your code?

Comment: How you are adding that tableview? how do you know you can't scroll it?

Comment: Are you facing this issue at run time or only on storyboard?

Comment: Table view have its own property to scroll so there is no need of scroll from ur end check scrolling is on or not and check your code.

Comment: @AshutosSahoo yes, There is no need to add any code to scroll table view. But i am facing scroll issue for https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu library.

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem You can find code : github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu. Here you need to add extra cells. In Main.Storybroad file add more than 20 cells for SideMenuTableViewController

Comment: @HiteshBorse did you checked the example still they have that issue as well

Comment: ya @AshutosSahoo. By mistake, I used that library. Is there any way to solve that scroll issue? That issue is due to gesture.

Comment: Fixed. ByDefautl table scrolling disabled. Enable table scrolling using self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByDefautl table scrolling was disabled. Enable table scrolling.

```
self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue on storyboard then increase the height of `UIViewController` using the following steps:

Click on `UIViewController` -> Select the size inspector -> Select simulated Size as Freeform -> increase height value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I aware of that. You can find code: github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu. Here you need to add extra cells. In Main.Storyboard file add more than 20 cells for SideMenuTableViewController.

Comment: Fixed. ByDefautl table scrolling disabled. Enable table scrolling using self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true